# Condition under which a matrix has three different eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the $3\times 3$ matrix 
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}1& -1& 0\\1& -2& -1\\k&  0&  0\end{bmatrix}$$

For what values of  does this matrix have three district eigenvalues.

I already found the top value which is $1$ ($k<1$) but don't know how to get the lower value.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $p(x)=-x^3 -x^2 + x + k$. The derivative of it is $-3x^2-2x+1$, which has roots $x=-1$ and $x=1/3$. In order for the characteristic polynomial to have 3 distinct roots we need $p(-1)<0$ and $p(1/3)>0$. This is, the stationary points of the cubic must be one above and one below the $X$ axis.

Comment: The condition $p(-1)<0$ is the one you already found $k<1$. From $p(1/3)>0$ we get $-\frac{1}{27}-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{3}+k>0$, i.e. $-\frac{5}{27}<k$.

Comment: @Rachel There is no lower value and no upper value if you just want three distinct eigenvalues. It's enough that $k\ne -5/27\land k\ne 1$. I have edited my answer to explain that

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic polynomial is $P(x)=k-x^3-x^2+x$

The third degree equation $x^3+x^2-x-k=0$ has discriminant

$\Delta=-27 k^2+22 k+5$

If $\Delta \ne 0$ then the equation has  three distinct  roots

$-27 k^2+22 k+5\ne 0 \to k\ne -\dfrac{5}{27}\land k\ne 1$

Hope this helps

Comment: whats wrong with three roots where you have an imaginary pair, aren't those distinct?

Comment: @Gregory You are right: I misread and thought that the OP wanted real roots